# ValueError: shapes (62,6) and (5,) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, shapes, predict

I am trying to predict the price but getting this error. I don't know how the predict() function is predicting the price and how the shapes are not aligned.

```
x_test_new = x_test[x_train_new.columns]
x_test_new = sm.add_constant(x_test_new)
y_pred = lm.predict(x_test_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshaping your array will do the job. But before you start doing that, let me tell you something which will save you some time.

The arrays used in scikit-learn, pandas, or let's say for convolutional neural networks are in matrix format. Let's say you have a matrix of 2 x 3 element like--

```
train = [
    [255, 255, 246],
    [246, 234, 232],
    [234, 222, 156]
]
```

Now if you want this array to be reshaped to put into your model, you can only reshape them in 3 x 2 format. If the array is even bigger, let's say it has 5 x 4 elements then you can reshape it in 4 x 5, 2 x 10, 10 x 2, meaning that the product of the dimensions of the reshaped matrix should be equal to the product of the dimensions of the original matrix.
The function is--

train.reshape(***the dimensions for new shape***)

If it doesn't work, please post the whole code.